# The volume of a hyperboloid of one sheet (symbolab can not solve integral ? )

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I just learned about Double integrals. I am trying to find the volume for an object that I have using Double integrals. That object is a one sheet hyperboloid and has the following equation for the given domain :

[Integrating the two variable function where the expression inside the integrals is equal to z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAEkZ.png)

As you can see, Symbolab returns "cannot solve". I tried other softwares such as Wolfram Alpha and GeoGebra CAS calculator but no luck. Plus, I tried integrating a hyperbolic paraboloid on Symbolab with as much details in its function as in the function of this one sheet hyperboloid, and it worked just fine and gave me the right result. Does anyone have any idea why all those softwares cannot solve that integral ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the expression under root becomes [negative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2.64+%28x+-+1.04%29%5E2+-+2.8+y%5E2+%2B+2%3E0+where+x%3D-1.292..1.292+and+y%3D0..1.0882) in the region you are trying to integrate.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how to interpret this plot and how does the equation in the square root inform you about the entire function ? Also, can the fact that the full hyperboloid is not a function and is symmetrical about the xOy plane explain this too?